# How would I go about citing Twitter's terms of service?

Tags: citations, social-media

I am trying to have Twitter's terms of service as a source of a paper I'm writing. I have been looking it up for several days and have found no answer.

How should I cite Twitter's terms of service?

Comment: Which academic style guide are you following? Do they have instructions for citing "a website" or something similar?